# How do I config the button that's clicked in a function whilst already using parameters on that button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, lambda

I need to be able to config the button that is clicked inside a function whilst using the function for multiple buttons

Iv'e seen people use the parameters to call the name of the button in the fucntion, however I've already used the parameters for a necessary part of my code so I am unable to do this

```
clicked = 0
def click_place(position):

    while clicked < 6:
        clicked += 1
        place_positions.append(position)
        .config(bg="yellow") #where I need help


#placement buttons
place_buttons = Frame(window)

place_positions = []

but1 = Button(place_buttons, height = 2, width = 5, command= lambda:click_place('A1'))
but1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

but2 = Button(place_buttons, height = 2, width = 5, command= lambda:click_place('A2'))
but2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)


place_buttons.place(x=250, y=500, anchor=CENTER)
```

Comment: Why not pass more than one parameter?  `click_place(but1, 'A1')` for example, so you have both the button and the string to work with.

Comment: Read [Get the text of a button if clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205482/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to store your buttons in a dictionary using `'A1'` and `'A2'` as keys

```
buttons = {
    'A1': but1,
    'A2': but2,
}
```

Then, given that `position` will be set to `'A1'` or `'A2'`, you can reference the button at `position` with `buttons[position]`.

Another solution is to pass the button as a parameter:

```
def click_place(position, button):
    ...
...
but1 = Button(place_buttons, height = 2, width = 5)
but1.configure(command= lambda:click_place('A1', but1))
...
```