# Is there any way to get some imformation of the button I have pressed when some buttons bind the same event-function in tkinter of Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I want to make a 4x5 buttons list so I did this in python:

```py
for i in range(4):
    seats_btn_row = []
    for j in range(5):
        btn = Button(self.fra_seats, text = str(i+1) + "-" + str(j+1), image = self.img_seat_takable, command = self._on_button_clicked
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
        btn.grid(row = i+1, column = j+1)
        seats_btn_row.append(btn)
    self.seats_btn_list.append(seats_btn_row)
self.fra_seats.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
```

it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzgoR.jpg)

and in the `self._on_button_clicked` function, I want to know which button I have pressed(the row and the column of the button), actually I tried to get the button's text attributes but failed to make it.

Is there any way to know some information of the `ButtonPressEvent`'s source button?

I have tried `.bind` function and command parameter

Comment: Read [Get the text of a button if clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205482/7414759)

Comment: It definitly works! Thank you very much, have a good day! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working on a way to return the text of a button after the button is clicked in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195702/working-on-a-way-to-return-the-text-of-a-button-after-the-button-is-clicked-in-t)