# how to change values ​in buttons done in a loop Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

how to change values ​​in buttons done in a loop?

I mean a different text, a command for each of the resulting buttons.

the program counts files in a given folder, then this value is passed to the loop that displays the appropriate number of buttons.
here is the sample text:

```
files = os.listdir(".")
files_len = len(files) - 1
print(files_len)

def add():
    return

for i in range(files_len):
        b = Button(win, text="", command=add).grid()
```

Comment: you can show it with an example?  I'm a beginner and I don't understand many things

Comment: Read [Get the text of a button if clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205482/7414759)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to change the `Button`'s text, because you can just put the filename in when they're created (since you can determine this while doing so).

To change other aspects of an existing `Button` widget, like its `command` callback function, you can use the universal `config()` method on one after it's created. See [Basic Widget Methods](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm).

With code below, doing something like that would require a call similar to this: `buttons[i].config(command=new_callback)`.

To avoid having to change the callback function after a `Button` is created, you might be able to define its callback function *inside* the same loop that creates the widget itself.

However it's also possible to define a single generic callback function outside the creation loop that's passed an argument that tells it which `Button` is causing it to be called — which is what the code below (now) does.

```
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter as tk


win = tk.Tk()

dirpath = Path("./datafiles")  # Change as needed.
buttons = []

def callback(index):
    text = buttons[index].cget("text")
    print(f"buttons[{index}] with text {text!r} clicked")

for entry in dirpath.iterdir():
    if entry.is_file():
        button = tk.Button(win, text=entry.stem,
                           command=lambda index=len(buttons): callback(index))
        button.grid()
        buttons.append(button)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, there is still a problem with the displayed file extension next to the name and command.

Comment: marcin: The extension can easily be removed—see updated answer. I also modified it to create a `list` of the `Button` widgets created and described how to change them after creation.

Comment: marcin: Based on your (now deleted) follow-on comment, I modified my answer again to show how to pass an argument to a more generic callback function that indicates which `Button` widget click caused it to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. By making a list.

```
files = os.listdir(".")
files_len = len(files) - 1
print(files_len)

def add():
    return
b=[]
for i in range(files_len):
        b[i] = Button(win, text="", command=add).grid(row=i)
```

Comment: thank you, how can I make each of the buttons perform a different function?